# How to change exception from ERROR to WARRNING in Hazelcast

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

How to change exception level from ERROR to WARNING in hazelcast. How to customise the hazelcast global exception handler?

```
2022-04-07 15:07:06,094 [ERROR] [hz.laughing_bhabha.partition-operation.thread-0] 
[c.h.m.i.o.EntryOperation]: [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [5.1] Session is not found.
com.product.ecom.str.api.SessionNotFoundException: Session is not 
found.
at com.product.ecom.str.impl.hazelcast.UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.updateSessi 
on(UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.java:81) ~[hazelcast-server-dependencies.jar:?]
at com.product.ecom.str.impl.hazelcast.UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.process(UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.java:64) ~[hazelcast-server-dependencies.jar:?]
at com.product.ecom.str.api.hazelcast.UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.process(UpdateSessionEntryProcessor.java:18) ~[hazelcast-server-dependencies.jar:?]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.process(EntryOperator.java:338) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKeyValueInternal(EntryOperator.java:193) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperator.operateOnKey(EntryOperator.java:176) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.EntryOperation.call(EntryOperation.java:193) ~[hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:273) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:248) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:213) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.run(OperationExecutorImpl.java:411) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.runOrExecute(OperationExecutorImpl.java:438) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvokeLocal(Invocation.java:601) [hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
at 
com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:580) 
[hazelcast-5.1.jar:5.1]
```

Hazelcast.xml

```
<properties>
        <!--
            ZIP and TAR distributions binds only to loopback network interface (127.0.0.1),
            Docker image listens on all interfaces (wildcard address).
         -->
          <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.socket.bind.any">false</property>
    </properties>
```